# Searchable select input without JS initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I need a searchable select input, which does not need to be initialized in JS. I use `Ajax` on my site, so you can not know how many selects come and their id before the call, so something `data-list` solution would be OK, but user should not send typed input and this should work like select input, where there is an id and a label defined, label is shown and id is sent. Can you help me? The only solutions I found needed a JS initialization like this:

```
$(".js-example-disabled").select2();
```

But we don't know id before the AJAX call, nor the number of select inputs we need to handle.

Comment: You can initialize selects after ajax call in success handler

Comment: Not if you don't know the number and id's before the call, as I know.

Comment: After getting the response from ajax call, after rendering the selects on the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your own select element in the `success` handler of your AJAX call. Then when you've added it to the body initialize it with `.select2()`. The only thing to consider here is the placement in the document.

```
function dynamicSelect2(url, placement) {
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
      var $select = $('<select></select>');
      $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        $select.append(`<option value="${item}">${item}</option>`);
      });
      $select.appendTo(placement);
      $select.select2();
    })
  });
}
```

I've wrapped it in a function so that you can dynamically change your data endpoint and placement in the body.

```
dynamicSelect2('yourdata', document.body);
```